# performance of enum class vs c style enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I am currently using enum class to 
- create an array with the number of elements in the enum 
- and index into the right values into the array at the time of usage

```
enum class mytype {type1, type2, type3, numoftypes};

class1 myarr [numoftypes];
```

unlike c style enums I have observed cpp enum classes are not native integers, I need to use static cast to make them integers

"I understand static casts are compile time replacement "

so when I use an enum class to index into my array at any time is there a performance hit? I was experimenting with the enum classes code and based on the compiler errors I could see they do not behave like c style enums.

Is there a performance hit I am taking to using enum classes over enums?

Comment: What results did you get when you measured the performance of each method?

Comment: Strong enums (`enum class`) were specifically added to C++ for the case where you *don't* want them to convert to integers. If you want the conversion, you can use "C style enums" in C++ too.

Comment: the binary code when you use `enum class` absolute the same if you use old style enum. `i = static_cast<int>(mytype::typeX)` not produce any additional binary code. binary code will be as for `i = mytype::typeX`.

Comment: There are no performance difference between `enum class` and regular enum. the first has "stronger" type.

Comment: @GregHewgill I haven't run performance by itself (I would want to do it, still thinking what would be the right approach to it )

Based on the compile errors I saw on enum classes I understood they were not raw integers like enums, hence I was wondering about the performance

Comment: @BoPersson I understand , its about project conformity, most places use enum classes

Comment: @ajax_velu Just a note, these are referred to as _scoped_ and _unscoped_ enums.